# In the combinatorics of a microcanonical ensemble, why do we count some permutations as distinguishable and others as indistinguishable?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I'm reading Greiner's good textbook "Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics" and I'm stuck on equation 6.22 on page 147 where he's counting the "number of ways" (aka countable permutations) that a microcanonical ensemble of N systems can be distributed to different locations of phase space.

See attached page 147 from the book, where equation 6.22 claims that swapping two systems that lie in different microstates is countable as a "different way" of generating the distribution, but swapping two systems within the same microstate is NOT countable as a "different way" of generating the distribution.  Why is this?

[image]

ALSO, I have one follow-on question about the same topic regarding the next paragraph of Greiner's book (next page, page 148 pasted below): what is the difference between $\omega_i$ and $p_i$?  They seem like exactly the same probability!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The idealization that Greiner is making is that each cell in phase space corresponds to a single state.

If we know particles 1 and 2 are in state 1, then that is all there is to say about the occupation of state 1. It isn't meaningful to say whether particle 1 "comes before" particle 2 or "comes after" particle 2.

Concretely, imagine the state space describes a vat of some liquid. Say we have carved up the volume of the vat into tiny cubes. To describe the state of the vat, we can specify which cube each atom has ended up in. Say we find particles 1 and 2 in cube number 1. That is all the information there is to know about cube 1.

On the other hand, knowing which particles are in which state *is* meaningful information (assuming the particles are distinguishable, which we are assuming here). So there is a difference between:

"particle 1 is in state 1 and particle 3 is in state 3"

and

"particle 3 is in state 1 and particle 1 is in state 3"

The reason is because states 1 and 3 are **different states**, so it is meaningful to ask which particles are in state 1 and which particles are in state 3.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I see. The confusion arose from poor word choice (on behalf of Greiner) since he used the phrasing "number of ways" which uses the word "WAYS".  The word WAY implies chronological dependence, but I hear you saying it doesn't matter whether particle 1 or 2 was FIRST in arriving.

Comment: This brings up the important follow-on question: if our systems are indistinguishable (e.g. monatomic gas pcls) then how can we ever distinguish between "particle 1 is in state 1 and particle 3 is in state 3" and "particle 3 is in state 1 and particle 1 is in state 3" ?

Comment: Also the presumption with stat mech ensembles is that the ensemble is of identical systems... how would you ever tell them apart without altering them?  These details alter the combinatorics!  It's a bit strange to me to ever be able to measure the difference between "particle 1 is in state 1 and particle 3 is in state 3" and "particle 3 is in state 1 and particle 1 is in state 3" ... can you elaborate? Are you confident that we can't find somewhere an example of an ensemble of indistinguishable systems? Why can't we use hydrogen atoms as our systems? They would be indistinguishable correct?

Comment: @dturn805 This is a subtlety that will surely come up later in the book. Quantum mechanically, if you are dealing with a gas particles of the same type (eg, electrons photons, or Helium-4 atoms), then indeed you *cannot* distinguish the state "particle 1 in state 3 + particle 3 in state 1" from the state "particle 3 in state 3 + particle 1 in state 1". This changes the statistics, so you derive the Fermi-Dirac or Bose-Einstein distributions instead of the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.

Comment: The assumption in the derivation Greiner is giving is that the particles are distinguishable. That's reasonable if you have a mixture of many particle types, and also is a good approximation to "hot" quantum systems where the indistinguishability only has a small effect on the answer.

Comment: Andrew, I thank you for your reflections on this...  I'll forge ahead into the deeper chapters of the book and see what I discover.  Many thanks.

Comment: Andrew do you have any idea on difference between  and ?  See end of my question....

Comment: @dturn805 To be honest, I don't particularly like the the way Griener treats this step. What he is doing is introducing the possibility that each energy level has different *degeneracies* -- that is, different numbers of microstates corresponding to the same total energy. A different derivation that I personally find more readable and which produces the same result is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_statistics#Derivation_from_microcanonical_ensemble (see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/700480/27732)

Comment: I think what Griener is saying on page 147 is that he will calculate $W(\{n_i\})$, which is the number of ways to assign particles to distinct energy levels (this calculation does not care about degeneracies), then on page 148 he wants to calculate $W_{\rm tot}(\{n_i\})$, which also incorporates the number of ways the $n_i$ can be distributed within the energy level. In my answer I was assuming there would be no degeneracies, but if there are multiple distinct microstates within the same energy you should account for this.

Comment: ({}) is a raw number count (much greater than 1) while tot({}) is a probability (ranges between 0 and 1).      Greiner very clearly says "Let  be the probability of finding one system within the surface element"... and it seems to me that  and pi are the same thing.

Comment: @dturn805 Honestly I find Greiner's development not very clear. I recommend looking at the wikipedia article I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

The squares in Fig 6.4 represent *macroscopic systems*, each consisting of a large number of particles.

Next we count the number of squares that are in the same *microstate*, i.e., their particles are in exactly the same position and have the exact same velocity.

Index $i$ is a counter that identifies individual microstates. The idea is that the big system is very big and is partitioned to a very large number of (macroscopic) squares so that a given microstate may appear $n_i$ times, where $n_i\gg 1$ (this is a thought experiment after all).

The multinomial factor counts the number of ways that a particular distribution $(n_1, n_2, \cdots)$ may be observed. For example, suppose $n_1=2$, which means that microstate 1 is observed in two squares out of $N$, but which two? *Any* two. In counting this number we remember that the squares are macroscopic and distinguishable.  Swapping two squares with *different* microstates counts as a new way to make the distribution. Swapping two squares with the *same* microstate does *not* count as a new way.

A simple demonstration can illustrate this. Suppose we have $N=4$ squares and two are in microstate 1 ($n_1=2$) and the other two in microstate 2 ($n_2=2$). The number of ways is
$$
   \frac{4!}{2! 2!} = 6
$$
and are enumerated below:
$$
   \begin{array}{cccc}
   \text{square 1} & \text{square 2} &  \text{square 3} &  \text{square 4} \\
   1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\  
   1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\  
   1 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\  
   2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\  
   2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\  
   2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\    
   \end{array}
$$

Comment: Yes, my confusion was over more subtle things than that, such as 1) the presumption with stat mech ensembles is that the ensemble is of identical systems, so how would you ever tell them apart without altering them? Wouldn't they be "indistinguishable" from each other?  These details alter the combinatorics! And 2) Even if you say that you CAN distinguish them, are you confident that we can't find somewhere an example of an ensemble of indistinguishable systems?  Why can't we use hydrogen atoms as our systems?  They would be indistinguishable correct?

Comment: @dturn805 1) the systems are identical at the *macroscopic level*, i..e, the have the same macroscopic properties.  We alter them *internally* by placing each at a different internal microstate. For example, a macroscopic  box subdivided into four parts labelled A, B C and D, all with the same energy, volume and number of particles. The parts are distinguishable and each can be at a different microstate. 2) Of course there are ensembles of indistinguishable systems. These obey different thermodynamics. If you are learning stat mech for the first time concentrate on (1) before you go to (2).

Comment: @dturn805 Perhaps the confusion arises from taking *identical* and *indistinguishable* to mean the same thing. They do not. To make some measurement we could prepare 4 identical samples and calculate the average of some property. The samples are identical in all respects but also distinguishable: we can  mark them with labels A, B, C and D. The labels do not make them less identical than before unless they interfere somehow with the measurement itself.

Comment: Thank you Themis.   What is your idea on difference between  and ?  See end of my question....

Comment: @dturn805 $\omega_i$ refers to the degeneracy of microstate $i$, i.e., number of ways that a particular microstate can be produced. In my combinatorial example, suppose that state 1 comes in two forms, "blue" and "red", then $\omega_1=2$. The total number of microstates would increase by $\omega_1^{n_1}=2^2$, corresponding to the four combinations of two 1's in two possible colors: red/red, blue/blue, red/blue and blue/red.

Comment: But the author clearly states that  is a probability...

Comment: @dturn805 If there are $\omega_i$ ways to form state $i$ the probability of the state is $\omega_i/\sum_i \omega_i$. That is, the probability of state $i$ is proportional to $\omega_i$.

Comment: well the author is crystal clear that  is a raw probability.  Also the wikipedia page for the Multinomial Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution; which covers this topic) is clear that the   terms are probabilities.   Do those facts change your answer?

Comment: No, because $\sum_i\omega_i$ is a constant. To say that the probability of state 1 is twice that of state 2 is the same as to say that state 1 appears in two colors and state 2 in one.

Comment: So you disagree with Wikipedia's description of the probability density of a Multinomial Distribution?

Comment: If it wasn't a probability, why would the author state "Let  be the probability of finding one system within the surface element"?

Comment: @dturn805 I agree with Wikipedia: if you set $p_i=\omega_1/A$ in the multinomial distribution, where $A$ is constant, you get Greiner's eq 6.23 multiplied by a constant ($1/A^N$), which makes $W_\text{tot}\{n_i\}$ a *probability*. Greiner is a bit sloppy with notation, the $W$ in 6.22 is *number* of ways to make the distribution but $W_\text{tot}$ in 6.23 is *probability*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145411/discussion-between-themis-and-dturn805).